# Scraping different style of Json

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am familiar with scraping data in this format.

```
  {"data":[{"assists":0,"assistsPerGame":0.0000,"evAssists":0,"evPoints":0,"gamesPlayed":1,"goals":0,"penaltyMinutes":0,"playerBirthCity":"Windsor","playerBirthCountry":"CAN","playerBirthDate":"1996-02-07",

import csv
import requests

outfile = open("NHL_Recent.csv","a",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Player","Pos","GP","G","A","P","+/-","PIM","PPG","PPP","SHG","SHP","GWG","OTG","S","S%","TOI","Shifts/PG","FOW%"])

req = requests.get('http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/skaters?isAggregate=true&reportType=basic&isGame=true&reportName=skatersummary&sort=[{%22property%22:%22shots%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22}]&cayenneExp=gameDate%3E=%222017-11-4%22%20and%20gameDate%3C=%222017-11-10%22%20and%20gameTypeId=2') 
data = req.json()['data']
for item in data:
    Player = item['playerName']
    Pos = item['playerPositionCode']
    GP = item['gamesPlayed']
```

But not in this manner.

```
"totalItems" : 600,
          "totalEvents" : 0,
          "totalGames" : 600,
          "totalMatches" : 0,
          "wait" : 10,
          "dates" : [ {
            "date" : "2017-10-04",
            "totalItems" : 4,
            "totalEvents" : 0,
            "totalGames" : 4,
            "totalMatches" : 0,
            "games" : [ {
              "gamePk" : 2017020001,
              "link" : "/api/v1/game/2017020001/feed/live",
              "gameType" : "R",
              "season" : "20172018",
              "gameDate" : "2017-10-04T23:00:00Z",
              "status" : {
                "abstractGameState" : "Final",
                "codedGameState" : "7",
                "detailedState" : "Final",
                "statusCode" : "7",
                "startTimeTBD" : false
              },
              "teams" : {
                "away" : {
                  "leagueRecord" : {
                    "wins" : 1,
                    "losses" : 0,
                    "ot" : 0,
                    "type" : "league"
                  },
                  "score" : 7,
                  "team" : {
                    "id" : 10,
                    "name" : "Toronto Maple Leafs",
                    "link" : "/api/v1/teams/10",
                    "venue" : {
                      "name" : "Air Canada Centre",
                      "link" : "/api/v1/venues/null",
                      "city" : "Toronto",
                      "timeZone" : {
                        "id" : "America/Toronto",
                        "offset" : -5,
                        "tz" : "EST"
                      }
                    },
                    "abbreviation" : "TOR",
                    "teamName" : "Maple Leafs",
                    "locationName" : "Toronto",
                    "firstYearOfPlay" : "1926",
                    "division" : {
                      "id" : 17,
                      "name" : "Atlantic",
                      "link" : "/api/v1/divisions/17"
                    },
                    "conference" : {
                      "id" : 6,
                      "name" : "Eastern",
                      "link" : "/api/v1/conferences/6"
                    },
                    "franchise" : {
                      "franchiseId" : 5,
                      "teamName" : "Maple Leafs",
                      "link" : "/api/v1/franchises/5
```

This is what I have so far with no success.

```
import csv
import requests
import os

outfile = open("NHL DIF JSON.csv","a",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Date","Game","gamep"])

req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?startDate=2017-10-04&endDate=2018-04-30&expand=schedule.teams,schedule.linescore,schedule.broadcasts.all,schedule.ticket,schedule.game.content.media.epg,schedule.radioBroadcasts,schedule.metadata,schedule.game.seriesSummary,seriesSummary.series&leaderCategories=&leaderGameTypes=R&site=en_nhl&teamId=&gameType=&timecode=') 

data = req.json()['dates']


    for item in data:
        Date = item['date']
    ##for item in games:
        Game = item['0']
        gamep = item['gamePk']



        print(Date,Game)

        writer.writerow([Date,Game,gamep])
    outfile.close()

    os.system("taskkill /f /im pythonw.exe")
```

I Would like to pull the "gamePk", "gameDate" from totalGames along with the teamNames within "teams" and other categories. I eventually would like to put that into a csv with the gamePk, gameDate, teams, score, etc. I'm just not sure how to get through the individual categories, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal json data, just a bit complicated.  You can get the date from `data['dates'][i]['date']`. For the teams, score, etc you have to iterate over `data['dates'][i]['games']`.

```
req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?startDate=2017-10-04&endDate=2018-04-30&expand=schedule.teams,schedule.linescore,schedule.broadcasts.all,schedule.ticket,schedule.game.content.media.epg,schedule.radioBroadcasts,schedule.metadata,schedule.game.seriesSummary,seriesSummary.series&leaderCategories=&leaderGameTypes=R&site=en_nhl&teamId=&gameType=&timecode=') 
data = req.json()

my_data =[]
for item in data['dates']:
    date = item['date']
    games = item['games']
    for game in games:
        gamePk = game['gamePk']
        gameDate = game['gameDate']
        team_away, team_home  = game['teams']['away'], game['teams']['home']
        team_away_score = team_away['score']
        team_home_score = team_home['score']
        team_away_name = team_away['team']['name']
        team_home_name = team_home['team']['name']
        my_data.append([date, gamePk, gameDate, team_away_name, team_home_name, team_away_score, team_home_score])

headers = ["Date","Game","gamep","gameDate","team_away_name","team_home_name","team_away_score","team_home_score"]

with open("my_file.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(my_data)
```

---

As for your last question, you can get the 'pk' from `data['gameData']['game']['pk']`.  The player, event, triCode and coordinates values are a little harder to get because some items don't have 'players' and 'team' keys, or the 'coordinates' dict is empty.

In this case the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method can be helpful because it will return `None` (or you can set a default value) if you try to access a non-existent key.
Still you have to design your code according to the structure of the json data, example:

```
req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020001/feed/live?site=en_nhl')
data = req.json()
my_data = []

pk = data['gameData']['game']['pk']
for item in data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']:
    players = item.get('players')
    if players:
        player_a = players[0]['player']['fullName'] if len(players) > 0 else None
        player_b = players[1]['player']['fullName'] if len(players) > 1 else None
    else:
        player_a, player_b = None, None
    event = item['result']['event']
    triCode = item.get('team', {}).get('triCode')
    coordinates_x, coordinates_y = item['coordinates'].get('x'), item['coordinates'].get('y')
    my_data.append([pk, player_a, player_b, event, triCode, coordinates_x, coordinates_y])

for row in my_data:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a little confusing until I dug in and made some edits. Added some new categories and ran into some errors a long the way but got them figured out and I understand the structure now. Is there a name difference between the Json formats from the above and below example?

Comment: Another quick question. Say under allPlays there is 0, 1, 2 to 300. do i have to list every 0 1 2 3 or can i do like for data in liveData ['plays']['allPlays']['0-300']['event']['coordinates']?   https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020001/feed/live?site=en_nhl   that is the link.

Comment: `data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']` is a list of dicts. You can take a list slice with the `:` operator (eg `data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays'][0:300]`) but if you want to select keys you have to loop over the the items in the list or select a single item (eg `data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays'][0]['coordinates']`)

Comment: I keep running into a TypeError: string indices must be integers. How would that look if i wanted to take the gameData [pk] and the [player] [fullName] [event] from result [coordinates][x][y] [team][triCode] from liveData dictionary?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, yeah that is a lot more in depth than i thought. I was able to go through  and add time for each action and make it write to a csv. Thank you very much for your time! Is there any articles you would recommend for ready material on this?

Comment: You should definitely start with python's  [built-in-types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types) (focus on [dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists)). It's quite a lot to read, but trust me it's very useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159319/discussion-between-michael-t-johnson-and-t-m-adam).